# What is the value that is being changed in numpy.random.binomial(n,p,size) for it to return different values?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I understand the the parameters of the `numpy.random.binomial` function and their meaning.

In the formula [image] we provide with the number of trials `n`, the probability for success `p` and the number of successful trials `N`.

**My question is:**

How does `numpy.random.binomial(20, 0.2)` return different values each time I call it?  How does that function decide `P(N)` so that it decides which `N` to return?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) you can see that `numpy.random.binomial` takes

- `n` is the number of trials of a binary experiment (i.e. sucess = 1, failure = 0).
- `p` as the probability for success (i.e. `1`)

" Returns
ndarray or scalar
Drawn samples from the parameterized binomial distribution, where each
sample is equal to the number of successes over the n trials."

so, to elaborate this a bit - it returns the number of successful experiments (i.e. `1`) that result after `n` trials with success probability of `p`.

And lastly, for your question on how does it decide on `N`, and the answer for that is that python uses a pseudo-random engine for all random operations. It uses the state of the machines' clock as a random seed to generate these random samples, but you can set the seed manually (to produce the same results when you want to guarantee the same output each time) with the `np.random.seed(NUMBER)`.

Cheers.

Comment: okay ,i kind of get it but still it doesnt answer my question on how P(N) is decided,N is returned to us when we use the function. How does it know what P(N) to use.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.random.binomial` doesn't output probabilities (like P(N)); rather, it generates random numbers with the binomial distribution given `n` and `p`.

There are many ways to simulate a binomial distribution.

A binomial generator *could* be implemented to choose an `N` uniformly at random, find the probability P(N), and return N with probability P(N) or discard it and try again (a *rejection sampler*), but it doesn't have to be implemented that way. The code for `numpy.random.binomial` is found at [legacy-distributions.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9ee262b5bf89e8c866a507e4d62b78532361adc2/numpy/random/src/legacy/legacy-distributions.c) at the time of this writing. Note that the legacy binomial sampler doesn't necessarily use rejection sampling; it uses either inversion or the BTPE algorithm (a specialized rejection sampler) depending on the parameters. Those are obviously not the only ways to generate binomial random numbers; another way is the trivial algorithm of counting the number of successful trials, and still other ways are described in chapter 10 of *Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation* by L. Devroye (1986). Note that some of these algorithms don't necessarily involve calculating P(N), at least directly; this is especially the case for the trivial binomial sampler.